# multiple sessions in different tabs in same browser window

Tags: .net

is there any way that we can have different sessions for different tabs in a same browser window, so that multiple users can be logged into same application in same browser window in different tabs using c#.net mvc.

if it is possible how to retreive session variables in different tabs in server side that is in c#

Thanks ,
L Sreedhar

Answer (score 0):

You can use session storage from your JavaScript `window.sessionStorage`.

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) says

> window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when
>   the browser tab is closed)